# LinkedList stack corrupted

Tags: c, list

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct listnode{
    int item;
    struct listnode *next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct _linkedlist{
    ListNode *head;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

void printList(LinkedList *ll);
int sizeList(LinkedList *ll);
int insertSorted(LinkedList *ll, int value);
int removeDuplicates(LinkedList *ll);

int main()
{
    int choice, i = 0;
    ListNode *temp=NULL;
    LinkedList *ll=NULL;

    printf("1. create LinkedList\n2. insertSorted\n3. removeDuplicates\nChoose an option: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter a list of numbers, terminated by the value -1: ");
        scanf(" %d", &i);
        while (i != -1){
            if (ll == NULL)
            {
                ll = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
                temp = ll;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp = temp->next;

            }
            temp->item = i;
            scanf(" %d", &i);
        }
        temp->next = NULL;
        printList(&ll);
        printf("Size of linked is %d", sizeList(&ll));
        break;
    case 2:

    default:
        break;
    }
}

void printList(LinkedList *ll)
{
    ListNode *temp = ll->head;
    if (temp == NULL)
        return;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->item);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int sizeList(LinkedList *ll)
{
    int size=0;

    ListNode *temp = ll->head;
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        size++;
        ll->size = size;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return ll->size;
}
```

I want to create a linked list and calculate the size of linked list and output it. I manage to get the size and print out the list but at the end, my program shows a debug error and state that Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'll' was corrupted. May I know why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that is incorrect is in your `main()` function.

```
if (ll == NULL)
{
    ll = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    temp = ll; // <- This is incorrect!!
}
else
{
    temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

`temp` is a `ListNode`, how can you assign it a `LinkedList`? Similarly, with that line, both `temp` and `ll` point to **the same memory** and operating on one will **overwrite** the other.

It should probably be something like:

```
if (ll == NULL)
{
    ll = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    temp = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    temp->next = NULL;
    ll->head = temp;
    ll->size = 1;
}
else
{
    temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

But that too is not as nice as it could be. I would prefer:

```
int main()
{
    int choice, i = 0;
    ListNode *temp=NULL;
    LinkedList ll = { NULL, 0 };

    printf("1. create LinkedList\n2. insertSorted\n3. removeDuplicates\nChoose an option: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter a list of numbers, terminated by the value -1: ");
        scanf(" %d", &i);
        while (i != -1){
            if (ll.head == NULL)
            {
                temp = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                ll.head = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->item = i;
            scanf(" %d", &i);
        }
        temp->next = NULL; // <- Please take a second look at this line. What happens if your first entry is -1?
        printList(&ll); // <- This too...
        printf("Size of linked is %d", sizeList(&ll)); // <- and this as well...
        break;
    case 2:

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

This is because there is no need to dynamically allocate the `LinkedList`. It is alive as long as the program is running and so there is no point in putting it on the heap.

There are other problems with your code and I would recommend **rubber ducking** your code and **strongly recommend reading [this link on debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**